# Finding the highest number in a set of numbers the user enters

Tags: c++

I bought the textbook *C++ How to program 9th edition* and I have come across a question that I am just stumped on, even though it is probably pretty simple. The question all summed up is this: "Use a while statement to determine and print the largest number of 10 numbers entered by the user". But here is the part that stumps me. The question wants me to use only 3 variables. counter, number, and largest. I know to make counter variable go up by 1 for each number entered until it gets to 10, and I know the number variable is used for input. I just can't seem to find out how to use the largest variable, or how to check to see what value is the largest without using other variables. This is all I have so far. Right now I put a break in the code so it wouldn't be an infinite loop.

UPDATED CODE

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
int counter = 0;
int number = 0;
int largest = 0;

cout << "Please enter up to 10 numbers and I will print the largest one on the screen.\n\n";

while (counter <= 10)
{
    cout << "Number: ";
    cin >> number;
    counter++;

    if (number > largest)
    {
        largest = number;
    }

    else if (counter == 10)
    {
        cout << "The largest number was: " << number;
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I suggest you check up on `if` statements.

Comment: Insert this line after cin >> statement. largest = number > largest ? number : largest;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the while loop, if number is greater than largest, then set largest = number.

Then at the end you can output largest.

Comment: Hmm. That actually makes a lot of sense. Though for some reason when I go through it all, it outputs a number that is not the largest one. For example when I was testing it, it said 93 was larger than 103

Comment: @Glorpy If that's your problem then put that code in the question; we can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: @cdhowie Right, sorry my bad.

Comment: Oh God I am an idiot. I am sorry for wasting your time, one sec let me change number to largest. Why do I program at 2 AM haha

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thank you very much for your help @Peter Carnesciali

Comment: I would remove the else if, and instead, put the cout line after the while loop is finished. No need for the extra logic of checking for the 10th count.

Answer (score 4):

```
cout << "The largest number was: " << number;
```

should be

```
cout << "The largest number was: " << largest;
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. It was my own stupidity that got the best of me. I should not program when my brain is half asleep haha. Thank you for your help

Comment: you're most welcome. Better double test before posting on stackoverflow though. I always use lots of `printf` or `cout` for debugging :)

Answer (score 2):

Solution(you don't even need a while loop)

```
#define MAX_NUM 8
//user input goes in myints
int myints[MAX_NUM] = {3,7,2,5,6,4,9};

// using default comparison:
std::cout << "The largest element is " << *std::max_element(myints,myints+MAX_NUM) << '\n';
```

Other Solution using int arrays even though you can replace int array with one variable

```
int main() 
{
    int largest = 0;
    int myints[10] = {3,7,2,5,6,4,9,7,2,6};
    for(int i =0 ; i< 10;i++)
    {
        if (myints[i] > largest)
        {
            largest = myints[i];
        }
    }
    cout << largest << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Compiled Code](http://ideone.com/EIWnmI)
[Second Compiled Code](http://ideone.com/a0QAMA)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add in while loop checking is the number you entered bigger than largest. If it is you just store it in largest. And actually you are entering 11 numbers because you count from 0 to 10. Just set counter to 1 or while(counter < 10)

```
int counter = 1;
    int number = 0;
    int largest = 0;

    cout << "Please enter up to 10 numbers and I will print the largest one on the screen.\n\n";

    while (counter <= 10)
    {
        cout << "Number: ";
        cin >> number;
        counter++;
        if (largest < number)
        {
            largest = number;
        }

    }

    cout << largest << endl;
```